# Android: voice call (chat) possibility using bluetooth RxAndroidBle library?

Tags: android, rxandroidble

Is it possible to make voice chat app using [RxAndroidBLE](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) library?
There are some issues related to writing long data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can write about what issues you expect to happen.

Comment: Thanks for response,
Issue happens were trying to write recorded audio data, the long write method can't achieve required throughput.

Comment: Maybe classic Bluetooth would be the right choice as BLE is meant for small amounts of data.